# Unable to Integrate Datadog APM with Meteor Application

Tags: docker, meteor, datadog, apm

I have tried to integrate Datadog APM with Meteor app, but it is not working. My meteor app is dockerized. Whenever I add the below configs for dd-trace within **Dockerfile**, container is getting started again and again (infinite loop)

```
RUN npm install dd-trace@3.13.2

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "--require", "dd-trace/init", "main.js"]
```

**Meteor version**: 2.5

Can anyone please assist me on this to resolve?

Thanks.